# Where do I get this regulator? Alternatives?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching, ldo

[image]

I am searching for this 3-pin IC.  It might be a low drop regulator switch. It is marked e3 N  1086 18 DR815.

It was faulty on a 42" LCD TV PCB. The TV could not turned on or switched from the standby to run mode. Hope someone can help me out what this IC is designed for and from which manufacturer it was and maybe you guys can show me an alternative part.

Comment: ST is a well known mfg, you might start there.

Comment: Many Thanks. Best help ever. Kind Regards.Simon

Comment: Thank you Brian Drummond for helping and sharing. I will start there. Kind Regards. Simon

Answer (score 2):

It might be an [ST LD1086](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld1086.pdf) voltage regulator in a DPAK housing.  It is rated for 1.5 amperes of output current.

[image]

The "18" on the second line would mean that it is a 1.8V regulator.

Comment: Regulators usually don't fail by themselves --- Something takes them out.   Look for bulging electrolytic capacitors.  https://bytecellar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/bulged_capacitor.jpg

Comment: Many Thanks for the Tip.I will check the capacitors. Best help ever. Kind Regards.Simon